# Must an instrument approach plate be visible during the approach?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures

Is there any legal requirement to display the approach plate for an IFR approach? Typically it's briefed as part of the descent checks and then kept on display - but I'm struggling to find any legal requirement to keep it visible.

Comment: "Legal requirement" where? Your profile says United Kingdom; are you interested in UK or EASA rules?

Comment: Why would there be one @andy-m? You cover the plate with a map and you're in breach.

Comment: Looking at EASA rules and regs.
@GdD - I'm not sure I follow, in breach of what?

Comment: If there is a regulation to display the approach plate and you cover it up you'd be in breach of the regulation @andy-m

Answer (score 4):

If you can't find any language for that sort of thing there probably isn't any.  At some point the value of regulations ends and you have to let common sense and good airmanship prevail.

Answer (score 1):

Under US 14 CFR 91, I am aware of no requirement for the plates to be on display.  The regulations do provide that the chart should be available, however.

One might ask themselves, prior to putting the charts in the case behind the pilot's seat...what would the accident review board have to say about this?